# Fitting multiple datasets with scipy curve fit, finding common parameters

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am attempting to fit multiple data sets to the same equation and to find the value of the fitting parameters between them. There are two independent variables, which I think I've dealt with. I ended up with something that works as expected for a single data set, but not one that works for multiple data sets. The code itself works, but the fit looks like a bow (a straight line and curved line connected at the end) instead of just a curve. I want separate curves per data set, with shared values for the parameters. I know I need to break up the data somehow, maybe by having my data stacked and adjusting the function with indexes, but I'm getting confused by the examples I've found and am not sure how to execute them here. Below is the code:

```
#import things
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

##set-up data##
#Have x-data as numpy array
xfrac = [1., 0.85,0.725,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.]
x = np.concatenate((xfrac,xfrac))
   
#Write function to generate and populate arrays using ideal values
#data sets (I have pasted the values instead of posting the code used to calculate them)
mix_850 = [1.701    3.642865 4.6762   5.0739   5.5177   5.9923   6.9408]
mix_1000 = [1.651185 3.53359  4.4854   4.8978   5.32525  5.7388   6.792]
dat = np.concatenate((mix_850,mix_1000))

#Temperature values
c=np.repeat(850.,7.)
d=np.repeat(1000.,7.)
Temp = np.concatenate((c,d))

#Define function
def f(Z, a1, b1, a2, b2):
    x1,T= Z
    x2= 1.-x1
    excess = a1+b1+(a2+b2*T)*(x1-(1.-x1)*(x1*(1.-x1)))
    ideal = ((x1*25.939)+((1.0-x1)*314.02))/(((x1*25.939)/1.701-0.3321e-3*T)+(((1.0-x1)*314.02)/7.784-0.9920e-3*T))
    mix = excess + ideal
    return mix

#Fitting
popt,_ = curve_fit(f,(x,Temp),dat)

fit_a1 = popt[0]
fit_b1 = popt[1]
fit_a2 = popt[2]
fit_b2 = popt[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `xfrac` as `np.array`:

```
xfrac = np.array([1., 0.85, 0.725, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.])
```

Use `xfrac` in the plot instead of `x`

```
# plotting
mix1 = f((xfrac, c), *popt)
mix2 = f((xfrac, d), *popt)

# temperature 1
plt.plot(xfrac, mix1, label=c[0], c='blue')
plt.plot(xfrac, mix_850, linestyle='', c='blue',
         marker='o', label='Data {}'.format(c[0]))

# temperature 2    
plt.plot(xfrac, mix2, label=d[0], c='red')
plt.plot(xfrac, mix_1000, linestyle='', c='red',
         marker='o', label='Data {}'.format(d[0]))

plt.xlabel('xfrac')
plt.ylabel('mix')
plt.legend()
```